# Skobbler 3.0.0 Search multistep callback onReceivedSearchResults not called

Tags: skmaps

I have installed offline maps on devices Storage and I am trying to search offline using `multistepSearch`. The function onReceivedSearchResults is not beeing called. 
When searching with `onelineSearch` returns `SK_SEARCH_MISSING_FILE(3)'. I have downloaded the map on storage: \Android\data\com.mymapsdemo\files\SKMaps\PreinstalledMaps\v1\20160426\package.
There are five map files: .ngi, .ngi.dat, .skm, .sym, .txg
The only difference to sample demo is that I am not using SQLite.

Am I missing some configuration files in order to be able to search offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend that you use the OneLine search experience as it works also in offline.
You can see an example of this in the demo project, the One Box Search menu entry (just set the connection mode to "offline" and you are ready to go).

Comment: Hello, as I sayed, I have tryied also onlineSearch but I receive SK_SEARCH_MISSING_FILE(3). Is there a special modification for offline search when maps are installed on Storage and not on SQLite.

Comment: Have you followed the steps described in the "multiple storages for map" chapter? http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec019

Comment: Hallo Adrian.B, Thank you for this information when I set the storage it works. This is the solution.

Comment: @OlimpiuOlar Could you please provide the code that solved the problem ? I have the similar issue and I don't know how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: @DavidSeroussi before searching:  searchManager = new SKSearchManager(this);
        SKStorageManager skStorageManager = new SKStorageManager();
        int returnValue = skStorageManager.addStoragePath(ApplicationData.getInstance().getMapResourcesDirPath() + "PreinstalledMaps/");